# Castle 3.0 Bound lifestyle - xml configuration

Tags: castle-windsor

is it already possible to use Bound lifestyle ([new lifestyles in castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/%28S%28kwaa14uzdj55gv55dzgf0vui%29%29/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx?HL=bound,lifestyle)) in xml configuration? Does anyone have some expirience with it?

Answer (score 0):

**Officially** *it is not*.

However, although discouraged (as is using XML configuration in general), it is possible.

In order for this to work you will need to, in addition to setting lifestyle to bound, specify `scopeRootBinderType` attribute.

Its value should be name of a type that should be used as your scope binder (i.e. figuring out which other component your scoped component should be bound to).

The scope  binder type needs to have a public default constructor and a method that takes `IHandler[]` and returns a single `IHandler` (that is it has to match the signature of the delegate that you can pass when you specify bound lifestyle via registration API in code).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take your advice and switch to registration API.